# Use all values of an enum in a JUnit parameterized test

Tags: java, junit, enums

I've found some examples how to use enum values in JUnit parameterized tests like this:

```
enum Colors {
  GREEN,
  RED,
  ORANGE
}

@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
  return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
    // How to use the complete enum here?
    {Colors.GREEN},
    {Colors.RED},
    {Colors.ORANGE},
  });
}
```

How can I use the complete enum in the `return` statement so that the test is run for each value of the enum?

Comment: I assume you are trying to do that with junit 4. Consider moving to junit 5, it has support of Enum sources (@EnumSource) for parameterized tests. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.1.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/EnumSource.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [the `values()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

```
Colors[] values = Colors.values();

List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>(values.length);
for (Colors color : values) { data.add(new Object[] { color }); }
return data;
```

Note that by normal convention the enum's name should be `Color`, not `Colors`: look at the enums in the standard library.